# Rescue Configuration for Cisco 3925

Tags: cisco, configuration

I recently upgraded our Cisco 3925 with the latest firmware and it returned a segmentation fault. I restarted it and now the console port won't connect.  Any ideas on how to restore the flash to a rescue configuration?

Comment: Is it storing its configs on an external flash? My other thought is that if the console port has reverted to default settings, which could have been reconfigured in the `running-config` that your router had before it rebooted.

Comment: Don't you get any output on the console port, even no bootloader?
If you could access the bootloader, you can try to flash a new firmware image with xmodem...

Comment: I can't seem to connect to the router through the tty. It gave me a segmentation fault and never came up again. I am using internal flash, the regular disk. I just changed the boot image and then committed it. It failed and I haven't been able to get it to work...

Comment: Sounds like a really bad problem. I don't think there is a simple way of recovery then. If you have checked that baud rate and everything else is correct and you still can't access even the bootloader, you'd better have a service agreement for the device. Sorry.